# What is a explanation in math to High School Students that why prove/disprove riemann hypothesis is important?

Tags: number-theory

What is a good mathematical explanation for High School Students that proving/disproving the Riemann hypothesis is important? I asked this because I wonder and want a comprehensive example why this question is worth a million (Is there even an application to elementary mathematics?). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Barry Mazur and William Stein are working on a non-technical [book](http://wstein.org/rh/). You can read the drafts now!

Comment: Nobody knows whether it is true or false! This might be starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at Dan Rockmore's book, "Stalking the Riemann Hypothesis", http://books.google.ca/books?id=cTVn9f9oKAgC

There are lots of connections to very cool things, but I don't know what would strike a high school student as important.